# Google Data .NET API Installer - Claims I need .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, google-data-api

I recently downloaded the Google Data .NET API from [this website](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-gdata/downloads) to use in C#. When I downloaded and ran the most recent installer for the Google Data API, it claims I need to install .NET Framework v2.0. However, I already have .NET v4.0 installed. The installer won't let me continue without "installing" .NET, but I already have a more recent version installed. All the information I have found on this API points back to the webpage where I got my installer, so the [page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-gdata/downloads) doesn't seem to be outdated. Do I need to downgrade and also install version 2.0?

Comment: If your system is a clean Windows 10 image, .NET 2.0 and 3.5 comes disabled by default. You need to enable it if the application targets 2.0 or 3.5, which it does given the problem. The 2.0/3.5 runs side-by-side with 4.0, so it doesn't matter at all that you have it installed (in fact, you most likely do **not** have 4.0 but rather 4.6.x or 4.7.x)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks for the comment! It appears that this was the issue for me.